# SQL Server : query to update record with latest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that maintains records of employers and employees' data. Something like this

```
EmployerName  EmployerPhone EmployerAddress  EmployeeName  EmployeePhone  EmployeeAddress   Date  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John              12345        NewYork         Harry        59786            NewYork        12-1-1991
Mac               22345        Bankok          John         12345            Delhi          12-3-1991
Smith             54732        Arab            Amar         59226            China          21-6-1991
Sarah             12345        Bhutan          Mac          22345            NewYork        5-9-1991
Root              85674        NewYork         Smith        54732            Japan          2-11-1991
```

I have another table that will have generic records on the basis of `phone number` (both employers and employees).

Table structure is as following

```
Phone Name Address
```

I want to put latest records `according to date` from `Table1` to `Table2` on the basis of `phone`..

Like this

```
Phone  Name    Address
-----------------------
59786  Harry  NewYork
22345  Mac    NewYork
59226  Amar   China
12345  Sarah  Bhutan
22345  Mac    NewYork
85674  Root   NewYork
54732  Smith  Arab
```

I've written many queries but couldn't find anyone resulted as required.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: means latest /newest entry according to date column

Comment: Create a view instead of that second table. (Or have computed columns.)

Comment: @jarlh didn't get you

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to move data around between tables. Too often systems end up with inconsistent data. Views, or computed columns, prevent this.

Comment: but its a one time activity

Comment: So the main table data will never change?

Comment: yes.. It will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

For initialize the table without phone duplicates:

```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 (Phone, Name, Address)
       SELECT X.* FROM (
            SELECT EmployeeName,EmployeePhone,EmployeeAddress FROM Table1             
            UNION
            SELECT EmployerName,EmployerPhone,EmployerAddress FROM Table1
           ) X
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Phone FROM Table2 WHERE Phone=X.Phone)
```

Comment: If the phone is unique put an unique index to this field. Otherwise you will have to do two queries one for insert and one for update

Comment: I'm okay with two queries too. because its only a one time activity.

Comment: Add the filters that you want over the Table1 selects

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for if I understand your question correctly. Should work for a once-off

```
DECLARE @restbl TABLE
(
    Name            varchar(100),
    Phone           varchar(20),
    Addr            varchar(100),
    [Date]          date,
    RecType         varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @restbl
SELECT  EmployerName, EmployerPhone, NULL, MAX([Date]), 'Employer'
FROM    @tbl
GROUP BY EmployerName, EmployerPhone

INSERT INTO @restbl
SELECT  EmployeeName, EmployeePhone, NULL, MAX([Date]), 'Employee'
FROM    @tbl
GROUP BY EmployeeName, EmployeePhone;

WITH    LatestData (Name, Phone, [Date])
        AS
        (
            SELECT  Name, Phone, MAX([Date])
            FROM    @restbl
            GROUP BY Name, Phone
        )
INSERT INTO FinalTable (Name, Phone, [Address])
SELECT  DISTINCT ld.Name, ld.Phone, ISNULL(tEmployer.EmployerAddress, tEmployee.EmployeeAddress) AS [Address]
FROM    LatestData ld
        LEFT JOIN @tbl tEmployer ON ld.Name = tEmployer.EmployerName AND ld.Phone = tEmployer.EmployerPhone AND ld.Date = tEmployer.Date
        LEFT JOIN @tbl tEmployee ON ld.Name = tEmployee.EmployeeName AND ld.Phone = tEmployee.EmployeePhone AND ld.Date = tEmployee.Date
```